# Sending data to port does not seem to be working on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to send data to port 2003 I am using tcpflow to listen however i cannot see any data being printed or sent ?

Sending Data to port 127.0.0.1 2003

```
echo hello | nc localhost 2003
```

or

```
echo "test.count 4 `date +%s`" | nc -q0 127.0.0.1 2003
```

Listening Data

```
tcpflow -i lo port 2003
tcpflow: listening on lo
```

Comment: Is there any program listening for connections on port 2003?

Answer (score 0):

In TCP, you *don't* send data to a port. You send a *connection request* to a port, and if it gets accepted, you start sending data over that connection. (TCP Fast Start lets one bundle the data with the request packet, but `nc` doesn't do that.)

So if there's no program listening for connections at `127.0.0.1` port `2003`...

```
# echo test | nc -v 127.0.0.1 2003
nc: connect to 127.0.0.1 port 2003 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

...the data won't be sent at all.